# error: method does not override error in java

Tags: java, inheritance

Hi there im alvin and I just begineer at java and I got a message that @override is does not override or implement a method from the from the supertype this is my code

BangunDatar.java (Super Class)

```
public class BangunDatar{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("");
   }
   void keliling(){
       System.out.println("Menghitung keliling..");
   }

   void luas(){
       System.out.println("Menghitung Luas...");
   }
}
```

Persegi.java (Subclass)

```
package inheritnce;

public class Persegi extends BangunDatar {
   float sisi;

   @Override
   float luas(){
       float luas = sisi * sisi;
       System.out.println("Luas Persegi: " + luas);
       return luas;
   }

   @Override
       float keliling(){
       float keliling = 4 * sisi;
       System.out.println("Keliling Persegi: " + keliling);
       return keliling;
   }
}
```

Comment: In the superclass, the methods return nothing (`void`); in the subclass, they return `float`. That's not allowed.

Comment: owh, so its must be a same type right?

Comment: mostly, yes. You can sometimes change the return type; but not if it is void.

Comment: its works, thanks andy!